# Flask: render_template context containing line breaks

Tags: python, flask, line-breaks

In my flask application, I have the situation where the page I will load will contain information from the form of the previous page. Here is some example code:

```
s = ""
for row in cursor:
    s += "Name: " + row[0] + "<br/>Age: " + row[1] + "<br/>"
return render_template("name.html", ID=s)
```

The only problem is that the html tags appear as plain text and do not get rendered into the html. Is there a way for the `<br/>` to be translated as line breaks? I've tried using `\n` instead but it does not work.

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Does this functionality already exist elsewhere?

Comment: Shouldn't you just pass `cursor` to the template and loop in the template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't you just pass the data to the template and loop in the template?

```
return render_template("name.html", rows=cursor)
```

In the template:

```
{% for row in rows %}
    Name: {{row.0}}<br>Age: {{row.1}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do that...haha. But I am complete flask noob

Comment: As an additional bonus, the name will be properly escaped. For reference, here is the [documentation of jinja template](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/), which is the template engine used by flask.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know, ff I wanted to print the current iteration, say i, where would I declare it?

Comment: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for see table half a page down (with `{{ loop.index }}`)

Comment: awesome! you're really a life-saver.